# Why is my log file rewriting the previous file instead of appending to the file?

Tags: php, logfile

I am having trouble appending to my log file. If my log file is over 50 mb, then make a new log file. If not, then append to the previous file. I am not sure if I am using FILE_APPEND correctly. Would it be best to use fopen and fwrite?

Here is my code below:

```
//this is the file to test size to determine whether to append to it or start a new log file
        if ($latestFile != '') {
            $latestFileSize = filesize($latestFile);//file size in bytes (1/1000000 of MB)
        }

        if ($latestFileSize != 0) {
            $fileSizeThreshold = 50 * 1000000;//Threshold for log file size limit in bytes (50 MB)
            if ($latestFileSize > $fileSizeThreshold) {
                    //The latest results file deletion log file is over 50 MB in size, so create a new one
                file_put_contents("c:\\sites\\{$logFileName}", $log);
            } else {
                    //2. Troubleshoot why the FILE_APPEND is not working and fix it. What is the normal behavior of the FILE_APPEND?
                    //The latest results file deletion log file is NOT over 50 MB in size, so append log entry to latest one
                file_put_contents("c:\\sites\\{$latestFileName}", $log, FILE_APPEND);
            }
        } else {
                //This is the first file in the log directory. Create it.
            file_put_contents("c:\\sites\\{$logFileName}", $log);
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }//end if $handle
```

Comment: Are you sure $latestFileSize is not always == 0?  Nothing wrong with file_put_contents usualy, troubleshoot the logic first.  Make sure you do get to the file_put_contents with FILE_APPEND.

Comment: @Nic3500 You were correct. It was automatically going to my else statement because of what you mentioned. I changed that logic and the code I posted here now works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$latestFileSize` is not always == 0?

Nothing wrong with `file_put_contents` usually, troubleshoot the logic first. Make sure you do get to the `file_put_contents` with FILE_APPEND, as the way you use it is perfectly fine.